# PYSNMP 4.3.2 Issue with mibdump.py output

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

I have a custom MIB file `syzf-alarms.mib`. When I use `mibdump.py` to generate pysnmp supported python module with `mibdump.py  ~/syzf-ALARMS`, I get:

```
Source MIB repo
sitories: file:///home/sbhattac, file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs, http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs
Compiled MIBs destination directory: /home/sbhattac/.pysnmp/mibs
MIBs excluded from code generation: RFC-1212, RFC-1215, RFC1065-SMI, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1158-MIB, RFC1213-MIB, SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB, SNMP-TARGET-MIB, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC, SNMPv2-TM, TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB
MIBs to compile: syzf-ALARMS
Destination format: pysnmp
Parser grammar cache directory: not used
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: no
Do not create/update MIBs: no
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level 0)
Ignore compilation errors: no
Generate OID->MIB index: no
Generate texts in MIBs: no
Try various filenames while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs: syzf-ALARMS
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed:
Up to date MIBs: SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC
Missing source MIBs:
Ignored MIBs:
Failed MIBs:
```

Now it generates one `syzf-alarms.py/pyc` file at `home/sbhattac/.pysnmp/mibs`.

Now I am trying to use this module in my code:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 161)), cmdgen.ObjectIdentity('1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 211, 1, 24, 11, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 3, 3, 1').addMibSource('/home/sbhattac/.pysnmp/mibs', 'syzf-ALARMS'))
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 130, in _init
    p = __import__(self._srcName, globals(), locals(), ['__init__'])
File "syzf-ALARMS.py", line 8, in <module>
    ( Integer, ObjectIdentifier, OctetString, ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols("ASN1", "Integer", "ObjectIdentifier", "OctetString")
NameError: name 'mibBuilder' is not defined
```

What could be the reason be? Are the above steps okay?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest pysnmp, your code should look like this:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('syzf-ALARMS', 'someObject', 0)))
)
```

Where *someObject* refers to a scalar MIB object (OBJECT-TYPE) of your choice defined in your MIB.

You do not need to specify path to your MIB module if it resides in *~/.pysnmp/mibs/* -- this path is hardwired into pysnmp.

Also you may omit explicit *mibdump.py* compilation phase since the latest pysnmp invokes MIB compilation module (pysmi) automatically for your ASN.1 MIB source. You may need to specify path to ASN.1 MIBs via *addAsn1MibSource()* as explained [here](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/custom-asn1-mib-search-path.py).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please let me know which one is advisable to use mibvariable or ObjectType(ObjectIdentity())?

Comment: It is advisable to use ObjectType(ObjectIdentity). The MibVariable approach is obsoleted and is only supported for backward compatibility.